# Docker-Compose phpmyadmin and mysql together for local development

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose

```
version: "3.1"
services:

 redis:
  image: redis:alpine
  container_name: larablog-redis
```

the code was working fine until I added the following services

```
 db:
  image: mysql:8.0
  container_name: larablog-mysql
  working_dir: /application
  volumes:
    - ./src:/application
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=larablog
    - MYSQL_USER=larauser
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=larauserpass
  ports:
    - "8890:3306"


 phpmyadmin:
 image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
 environment:
        PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
        MYSQL_USER: larauser
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: larauserpass
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
 ports:
        - "80:80"
    links:
        # for mysql container
        - "db:db"
 volumes:
    db:
        driver: "local"
```

I am trying to follow a method I found on https://gotechnies.com/docker-compose-yml-mysql-phpmyadmin/ however I cannot start from scratch because I need the laravel framework as well

```
 webserver:
  image: nginx:alpine
  container_name: larablog-webserver
  working_dir: /application
  volumes:
      - ./src:/application
      - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  ports:
   - "8888:80"



 php-fpm:
  build: phpdocker/php-fpm
  container_name: larablog-php-fpm
  working_dir: /application
  volumes:
    - ./src:/application
    - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

I get this error when i try to run docker-compose up -d ...

```
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
in ".\..\docker-compose.yml", line 27, column 6
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
in ".\..\docker-compose.yml", line 35, column 9
```

How can I overcome this error?

Comment: It looks like your yaml is invalid. Check your file, format it properly and that error should go away. You can check your yaml here: http://www.yamllint.com/. This is just reference to YAML syntax: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/YAMLSyntax.html